# InstallShield 2012 hangs when calling Oracle SQL script

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I have an InstallShield 2012 InstallScript MSI project and I need to run Oracle SQL scripts.

My test script looks like this:

```
update zversion set comments = 'Oracle' where version = '1.30.1'
```

When ran the install hangs with the dialog saying: "Custom Action. Executing SQL Install Script..."

Last entry in log file:

MSI (s) (70:30) [16:05:31:054]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=ISSQLServerInstall,ActionType=1025,Source=BinaryData,Target=ISSQLServerInstall,CustomActionData=C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Temp\~E303.tmp)
MSI (s) (70:D4) [16:05:31:367]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIEF3A.tmp, Entrypoint: ISSQLServerInstall
1: Processing the SQL connection 'SQLServer'... 
1: Skip the SQL connection 'SQLServer'. This connection is specified in the IS_SQLSERVER_CXNS_ABSENT_FROM_INSTALL property. 
1: Processing the SQL connection 'Oracle'... 
1: Determining if there is at least one SQL script scheduled to execute under the connection... 
1: The SQL script 'SqlScript5.sql1' is scheduled to execute. Note that the final decision will be made later if you have a schema version specified for this script. Script Execution=RunOnInstall, Action=Install, Component State=Install, Schema= 
1: Attempting to establish the SQL connection... Server: P.PO.COM, Database: MSOW 
1: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed 
1: Attempting to execute SQL scripts... 
1: Determining if the SQL script 'SqlScript5.sql1' will be executed... 
1: The SQL script will be executed because no schema version is found on the target database. 
1: Prepare executing SQL script file: 'SqlScript5.sql1'. Path: 'C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Temp\~E314.tmp' 
1: Executing SQL at Line 3 >>>

Comment: More Info: My installation hangs when I run this Oracle SQL script. I am at a loss.

InstallShield 2012
InstallScript MSI project
Windows 7
Oracle client 11.2.0.1.0
AdoDriverName: Microsoft ODBC for Oracle
Connection:

    Command Timeout: 30 Seconds

    Batch Separator: GO

Script:

    UPDATE zversion
    set lastudchangedate = sysdate
    WHERE Version = '1.30.1'
    GO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

I deleted the old script file and created a new one.  Don't know what was wrong with the old file.